# everytime i get this error whie running my flutter app in vscode

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

[image]

Every time I get this error while running my flutter app in VSCode.

Anyone please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JDK, not a JRE and your Java install at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_281 is most definitely a JRE.

Also check https://dev.to/ejgamer21/install-flutter-without-android-studio-58bi for setting variables.